# When using feature-linked annotation in ArcGIS 10, can I create multiple annotations from one feature?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, annotation

I have a road that I want to create multiple annotations for. Is it possible to attach more than one annotation to the same feature?

Comment: I don't see why not. Define labels export to annotations, turn on the dynamic labels again, edit as needed and export to another annotation class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the setup is for ArcGIS 10, but in 9.3.1 on the Properties>Label tab you can define more than one label class for labeling.  Change the "Method" option to "Define classes and features and label each class differently."  You can then define a different field, placement properties, and expression for each class.  Alternatively, you could just only label one class, but concatenate multiple fields within the expression option (see example below).

[FIELD1]&" "&[FIELD2]

After you have your labels setup and labeled you can then convert them to feature linked annotations.

In addition, the [ArcGIS Resource Center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Common_text_related_tasks/00s800000015000000/) has much more literature on labeling and annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can control pretty well every facet of annotation behavior (placement, font, color, add symbols, rotation angle, multiple labels per feature, etc, etc .....> ).

....and yes, create your different annotations and organize them in a geodatabase.

Better explained by ESRI actually.  Everything you could want to know [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000m00000001000000.htm)